# Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection

I have a `CollectionChanged` event that is tied to an `ObservableCollection`. This `CollectionChanged` event then calls another function which is intended to update another collection (of the same type) with an item from the original collection. I have read other posts on the "*Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event*" and I understand completely why it is frowned upon to modify a collection inside of a `CollectionChanged` event and why this can result in a circular reference... but in this particular case I am not modifying the original collection, I'm only adding an Item from it to an unrelated collection.

So to my question.. is there anything wrong with what I am doing? I don't see how adding an item from the collection with the event tied to it to another collection would fire the event again and create a circular reference (although please tell me if I'm wrong about this).

Also... is there any way around it? I read several posts advising to run this on a separate thread but when I try that I get the following error instead.

```
This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection
from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.
```

I'm really just after a better understanding of what's going on here. Any advice would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

Simplified example as requested

```
void originalCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    update(originalCollection);
}

private void update(object parameter)
{
    foreach (var originalCollectionItem in parameter)
        newCollection.Add(originalCollectionItem);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The title of the post is the error message.. Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event

Comment: Could you post the actual code?

Comment: But if you are passing Coverages as the parameter to getCoverages then you are modifying THE collection in the foreach.  Coverages.Add.

Comment: The naming is the same in both but the original Coverages is the parameter in getCoverages... not the collection that is Coverages.Add() (I do realize how confusing that sounds as I type it sorry)

Comment: Then I recommend you break this down to a simple example that reproduces the problem and use unique names.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using WindowsForms just make sure to use the Invoke method on the Form to keep the executing code on the Dispatcher's thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invoke.aspx

Or, if using WPF use the Dispatcher class.

http://dotnetpattern.com/wpf-dispatcher

Comment: The second link appears to be broken. I'm redirected to https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues which contains no information about the problem or the proposed solution

Comment: @Blueriver I updated the link, it doesn't match the original but it should have the information necessary.